Outputting handwritten digits with a Neural Network
I know that you can use a neural Network to recognize handwritten digits. How would you then use that same neural network to output handwritten digits in the unique style of that network? In other words, how would you train a NN to handwrite digits?
When I look up this question I only see results on recognizing handwritten digits. I want to output them as well.
I know that they technically wouldn't be handwritten anymore but they should look like it.

Interesting question, but it's off topic here; I think datascience.stackexchange.com is a more suitable forum.

Thanks Robert, I'll post it over there.
